# Mind-mapping framework that is possible to export/import in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mind-mapping

I would like to know if there is any mind map that is open source and has similar functionalities like [WiseMapping](https://wisemapping.atlassian.net/wiki/). The possible problem with WiseMapping is that it has some server side code in Java and I would need only the client-side part. I will still try to extract the client-side part.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE.  Please specify the functionality you need from *WiseMapping* as not everyone is familiar with it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.